# Notification doesn't show on real HW(gear s3) but does on emulator

Tags: web-applications, notifications, tizen

I want to make notification with timer.
my code works on emulator but doesn't on my real HW.

I have power, internet, notification, application.launch privileges for my app.

Why it doesn't work?

var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl(
          "http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/create_content", null, "image/jpg", null);
      var notificationDict =
      {
        content: "This is a simple notification.",
        iconPath: "./logo_STEMS.jpg",
        soundPath: './sound_noti.wav',
        vibration: true,
        appControl: appControl
      };

```
  var notification =
      new tizen.StatusNotification("SIMPLE", "Simple notification", notificationDict);

  tizen.notification.post(notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated API. Use UserNotification instead:

Refer to "Note" at https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/notifications?langredirect=1